# Integral including Legendre and radical

Tags: integration, radicals, legendre-polynomials

I would appreciate if you help me with the integral $\int\sqrt{\beta^2 - x^2} P_n(x) dx$. As simple as it may look, I could not find it in the table of integrals of different handbooks.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int\root{\beta^{2} - x^{2}}{\rm P}_n\pars{x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &{1 \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}h^{n}{\rm P}_{n}\pars{x}
> \\[3mm]&\imp\quad
> \int{\root{\beta^{2} - x^{2}} \over \root{1 - 2xh + h^{2}}}\,\dd x
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}h^{n}\int\root{\beta^{2} - x^{2}}{\rm P}_{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x
> \end{align}
>   Integrates the left hand side and expands in power of $\ds{h}$. Mathematica can do that !!!.